# Remove white space before punctuation in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string

```
"This is a big sentence .  !  ?  !  but I have to remove the space ."
```

In this sentence I want to remove all the space coming before the punctuation and should become

```
"This is a big sentence.!?!  but I have to remove the space."
```

I am trying to use `"\p{Punct}"` but not able to replace in string.

Comment: So you want to remove all whitespace between chacters and punctuation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
newStr = str.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\p{Punct})", "")
```

[ideone.com demo for your particular string](http://ideone.com/a0Ag4)

Break down of the expression:

- `\s`: White space...
- `(?=\\p{Punct})` ... which is followed by punctuation.

Comment: I'd add a `+` quantifier to the  `\s` :)

Comment: Great It worked... Please could u explain then i could be able to make more of these

Comment: If i want to find the white space after the punctuation i should do (\\p{Punct}=?) or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex to find all whitespace in front of punctuation: `\s+(?=\p{Punct})` (Java String: `"\\s+(?=\\p{Punct})"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group and reference it in the replacing string:

```
String text = "This is a big sentence . ! ? ! but I have to remove the space .";
String replaced = text.replaceAll("\\s+(\\p{Punct})", "$1")
```

Here we capture the punctuation in a group with `(\\p{Punct})` and replace all the matched string with the group (named `$1`).

Anyway, my answer is a mere curiosity: I think @aioobe answer is better :)